# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n D_iF(g)dg_i=0$

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms

> Let $F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^4$ on $\mathbb R^n$, and let $\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:F(x)\leq 1\}$. Consider
>   $$
> \omega=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i+1}D_iF\,dx_1\wedge\dots\hat{dx_i}\dots\wedge dx_n.
> $$
>   a) Show that $\int_{\partial\Omega}\omega>0$.
>
> b) Let $g=(g_1,\dots,g_n)\colon\Omega\to\partial\Omega$ be a map of class $C^\infty$. Show that
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n D_iF(g)dg_i=0.
> $$

I managed to show part a using Stokes' theorem. However, I'm don't know how to solve b.

*edit*

After some help here and there, I finally found a solution. I've posted it as an answer, as there is really nothing left to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $d(F\circ g)=g^*(dF)$. The exterior derivative of $F$ is given by
$$
dF=\sum_{i=1}^n D_iF\,dx_i.
$$
So we're going to calculate the pull-back:
$$
g^*(dF)=\sum_{i=1}^ng^*(D_iF\,dx_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n g^*(D_iF)g^*(dx_i)=\sum_{i=1}^nD_iF(g)\,dg_i,
$$
where we used that $g^*dx_i=dg_i$. Now I need to argue that this equals zero. We know that $F(x)\equiv1$ on its boundary, and since $g(\Omega)=\partial\Omega$, we have $F\circ g\equiv 1$. This means that $d(F\circ g)=0$. This concludes the prove.